# How to setup a MySQL Database Connection with Spring in IntelliJ?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, xampp

I want to use XAMPP and MySQL for a local database in IntelliJ, but I have no plan how to do that...

Do you know some tutorials for setting it up?

Or are there alternatives in which I don't need to use PHP?

Comment: You can install MySQL and then connect from IntelliJ to the database. You don't need phpMyAdmin

Comment: Whats the difference?
@SimonMartinelli

Comment: You only need the database. No Apache, no PHP, no phpMyAdmin

Comment: But I'm prefering a WebServer with it's services

Comment: Why do you want a Webserver. You are writing a Java app

Comment: Well It's going to be a Web-App with Vue.js frontend

Comment: and you want to run Vue.js in Apache? Or do you want to embedd Vue.js in Spring Boot app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to integrate your IDE with your database. Just insert connection string and other stuff to application.properties file.

For example;

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

If you want to manage your db in IDE, you can follow this; https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/managing-data-sources.html